# How to separate bits from large data bits?

Tags: c#

I have some bits of data like `11111111000000001010101011111111`. I have to separate the first 8 bits of data and and display them **error code**. And then after the first 8 bits i have to read the remaining bits in a group of 8, one after another as **correct data**.

I am successful in separating the data in to group of 8 bits and reading them one after another,but i am not able to separate them as error code and correct data.

As I want to perform some operations on the correct data but not on the error data

I have stored the data bits as string of data and separated them by list method.

I want output as-

**error code** `11111111`

**correct data**-

```
00000000
10101010
..
..
```

The code i used for separating the bits in group of 8.

```
string s = "1111111100000000101010101111111111101011000111011011000101011111000000011111000100000111101011101111111001011110010111101111001100001011000000101110001011001111";
Console.WriteLine("Packet length : "+ s.Length);

List<string> yourStringList = new List<string>();          

for ( i = 0; i < s.Length; i = i + 8)
{ 
    yourStringList.Add(s.Substring(i, 8));
}  

foreach (string st in yourStringList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DATA :{0}", st);          
}
```

Comment: `yourStringList[0]` is error code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print error code firstly and then data:

```
Console.WriteLine("ERROR CODE :{0}", yourStringList[0]);    
foreach (string st in yourStringList.Skip(1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("DATA :{0}", st);          
}
```

Also, consider the case that if your string length is `length % 8 != 0`. In this case you should start from the end and read by 8 symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string remainingBits = "010011010100110101000101010011010100110101001101010011010100110101101111";
            List<string> octetCollection = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < remainingBits.Length / 8; i++)
            {
                octetCollection.Add(remainingBits.Substring(i * 8, 8));
            }

            foreach (var s in octetCollection)
            {
                //Do whatever action on each octet
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Count: " + octetCollection.Count.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```